# another $(...).datepicker is not a function error

Tags: django, jquery-ui

If this seems not-so-helpful (Noting the 'too localized' close votes), then please tell me why. I think Django and JQuery UI make a pretty good team so it's worth working out any gotchas about using them. The answer to this question is not something I've found documented or in another question and is relevant to use of other widgets in other places.

And on to the question...

---

I have a django project in development mode. Inside its static directory I have the following file structure:

```
directory: js
            jquery-1.9.1.js
            jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js
            other_stuff.js
directory: css
            directory: ui-lightness
                directory: images
                jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css
                jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.css
```

I'm trying to get the datepicker to work on one of my forms:

In my html head I have:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css"/>
<script src="/static/js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#id_date_of_birth").datepicker();
        });
</script>
```

And the input I am trying to change looks like:

```
<input type="text" size="10" id="id_date_of_birth" class="vDateField" value="1987-01-19" name="date_of_birth"/>
```

**Now I know this question has been asked like a billion times before but none of the listed solutions I have read so far seem to work...Can anybody hazard a guess as to why I am getting the error`$(...).datepicker is not a function` ?**

Stuff I've considered:

1. Everything seems to be included in the correct order. Other solutions mention including jquery ui's `...core.js` but I think everything is included in jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js because otherwise the jquery ui download page is very misleading (I chose to download every component and there is no effect)
2. No other errors came up except the one I mentioned. All scripts loaded correctly
3. Nothing is included more than once
4. I'm waiting until the document is ready before calling anything at all so my problem is not due to bad timing

Comment: Are you sure all scripts are loaded? The `<script>` tags are missing a closing `</script>` tag (it's needed even when loading external scripts), as you can see from the code highlighting.

Comment: @Juhana: yeah, I'm sure. I was copy-pasting from firebug. It helpfully omitted the closing tags. I've edited the question

Comment: @Juhana: I found the problem thanks to you! If you can guess what it was I'll mark you correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the link wanted a separate closing tag...

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.css"><link/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the directory structure you listed is accurate, your jquery files do not end with ".js", while your references to those files do have ".js" in the page header. Add the ".js" extension to your jquery files and it should work.

you should also close your input element:

```
<input type="text" size="10" id="id_date_of_birth" class="vDateField" value="1987-01-19" name="date_of_birth" **/**>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me several times.

What i did was to copy the whole code (script) and placed it in the parent view.

If you're trying to place the script in a partial it may not work, try to put it in a higher level until you get the job done.

One example in django-oscar i had to place the script in the basket.html template to make it work in here:

{% include 'basket/partials/basket_content.html' %}